# Update fields with data from a second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a database in PostgreSQL and I'm having some problems updating some values, let me explain.

I have three tables.

Table A:

```
  id  |  itemID  |  Value
```

Table B:

```
  Name  |  Value
```

Table C:

```
   itemID  |  Name
```

I need to update the value field on table A with the value from table B where the itemId from the tables A and C are equal.

I don't really know how to explain, please ask me anything so I can explain it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a join in the UPDATE statement:

```
update tablea 
set "Value" = b."Value"
from tableb b inner join tablec c
on c.name = b.name
where c."itemID" = tablea."itemID";
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rthibQAco9Mn7fEAe2WQdP/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Update` statement with a `Common Table Expression`, and bring the results directly by adding `returning` clause at the end.

```
with t0 as
( 
 select c.itemID , b.value
   from tableC c
   left join tableB b on b.name = c.name
)
update tableA a
   set value = t0.value
  from t0
 where a.itemID = t0.itemID 
returning a.*;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=20c2d02a658df4aa1cfc82ff9be8786e)</kbd>